# Are vpacks expensive?: doing fine grain performance measurement/profiling with mixed latex & luatex code

Tags: luatex, performance, profiling

How to do fine grain performance measurement with mixed latex, luatex code? Let's say there are two blocks of code, executed one after another. The first one is in plain latex, and the second is luatex. I would like to know the real overhead of adding the second piece of code. A test case that comes to mind is doing a vpack on an existing vbox that was not originally set to the the size of its contents. How expensive is a vpack compared to vbox creation? That's something I am actually interested in knowing, especially for huge vboxes for instance. Here's my the code that needs performance timer insertions (at marked locations):

(Note: Ignore "Natural height" value of tempvbox, its incorrect as the height exceeds tex limit. You can of course see a correct value by reducing the number of paragraphs in blindtext from 1000 to something small, though that will also reduce the accuracy of ratio of two time deltas in consideration.)

```
% >> lualatex <filename>.tex
\documentclass[notitlepage,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{printlen}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\uselengthunit{in}

\begin{document}

% Time1
\newsavebox{\tempvbox}
\setbox\tempvbox=\vbox to 4in{{\hsize=4in \noindent\blindtext[1000]}}

% Time2
\directlua{
    tempvboxnatural = node.vpack(tex.getbox('tempvbox').head)
}%
% Time3

Set height of tempvbox: \directlua{tex.sprint("\csstring\%f  in",(tex.getbox('tempvbox').height/tex.sp('1in')))}

Natural Height of tempvbox: \directlua{tex.sprint("\csstring\%f  in",(tempvboxnatural.height/tex.sp('1in')))}

%Print Time2-Time1, and Time3-Time2 here
Time2-Time1: ??

Time3-Time2: ??

Partial contents of tempvbox:

\vsplit\tempvbox to 6in

\end{document}
```

Screenshot of output:

[image: screenshot of compiled output]

Comment: As a side question, why is substring ' in' not printed by `tex.sprint` in above code?

Comment: For the % sign, I'd use `tex.sprint(-2, ...)` and `string.format()` to format the string. Otherwise TeX might interpret some characters like %. `tex.sprint(-2,string.format("\csstring\%f  in",(tex.getbox('tempvbox').height....`

Comment: For the timing, you can `os.gettimeofday()` to get the current time. Just get the time at the beginning and then at the end and subtract both.

Comment: @topskip I would recommend using `os.clock` over `os.gettimeofday` here because it is not influenced by changes to the system time.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Good point, thank you! I'll remember that for future use.

Comment: @topskip Thanks! I tried reading the description of value -2 in `tex.sprint(<number> n, <string> s, ...)`. Is -1 the default value when nothing is specified? And in layman's language when should -2 be used (I assume whenever there is a '\' in the string?)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger `os.clock()` behaves differently on Windows vs Linux/Mac. It reports wall clock time on Windows, and CPU time on Linux/Mac. I found multiple links on that different behavior: https://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=os.clock, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/clock?view=vs-2019. I came across some stackexchange posts on expl3 performance counters, do you know if that too has the same problem?

Comment: @reportaman I guess that with "expl3 performance counters" you mean "l3benchmark"? That one currently uses `os.clock` on LuaTeX while all other engines use gettimeofday. To make it more uniform, the next release will unify this to always use gettimeofday (even under LuaTeX). I still think that `os.clock` is better (especially since CPU time is much more useful for most benchmarking) but in this case consistency was more important. (See my comment at https://github.com/latex3/latex3/pull/796#issuecomment-678357951 for more about that)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Yes I agree, CPU time is much more useful and I will keep using `os.clock()`. Thanks for that pointer. IMO its l3benchmark might be better off just keeping the status quo, with a warning printed at the end of log when run on Windows machine (stating that Windows with l3benchmark reports wall clock time, and is thus not as accurate for certain perf profiling/comparison tasks). I don't understand the point about "consistency", as there will never be consistency in wall clock time anyway!

Comment: @reportaman If you want to discuss that, open an issue in the LaTeX3 repo. But the basic idea is that `\sys_timer:` has other uses where wall time is more appropriate, e.g. documenting how long a document took to compile. Such code should not suddenly change behavior when the engine changes. Also benchmarking can be used to determine difference in performance of different engines so there is value in measuring the same thing in all engines.

Answer (score 1):

Based on suggestions of Marcel Krüger & Patrick Gundlach (topskip), with some addition & testing, here's the final code & observations:

For paragraphs that are few lines long (`\blindtext[1]`), vpack takes 2% to 10% of time taken by its respective vbox creation. As the number of lines increase (`\blindtext[1000]` or a loop with `\blindtext[1]\par\blindtext[1]\par...`), percentage time taken by vpack compared to vbox creation keeps decreasing (for `\blindtext[1000]` it is on the order of 0.01% of time taken for vbox creation). Either way, percentage wise vpack seems insignificant as one could expect vbox creation is O(n^2) complexity and vpack probably O(n) complexity.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{printlen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\uselengthunit{in}

\begin{document}

% Time1
\directlua{time1 = os.clock(); texio.write_nl("time = " .. time1)}
\newsavebox{\tempvbox}
\setbox\tempvbox=\vbox to 4in{{\hsize=4in \blindtext[1]}}

% Time2
\directlua{time2 = os.clock(); texio.write_nl("time = " .. time2)}
\directlua{
    tempvboxnatural = node.vpack(tex.getbox('tempvbox').head)
}%
% Time3
\directlua{time3 = os.clock(); texio.write_nl("time = " .. time3)}

\directlua{texio.write_nl("(time3-time2)*100/(time2-time1) = " .. (time3-time2)*100/(time2-time1) .. " \csstring\%" )}


Set height of tempvbox: \directlua{tex.sprint(-2,string.format("\csstring\%f  in",(tex.getbox('tempvbox').height/tex.sp('1in'))))}

Natural Height of tempvbox: \directlua{tex.sprint(-2,string.format("\csstring\%f  in",(tempvboxnatural.height/tex.sp('1in'))))}

%Print Time2-Time1, and Time3-Time2 here
Delta1 (Time2-Time1): \directlua{tex.sprint(time2-time1)}

Delta2 (Time3-Time2): \directlua{tex.sprint(time3-time2)}

(Delta2/Delta1)*100: \directlua{tex.sprint((time3-time2)*100/(time2-time1))} \%

Partial contents of tempvbox:

\vsplit\tempvbox to 6in

\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of compiled output]

Comment: Actually both are O(n), but the hpack is so fast that you are measuring other stuff instead. E.g. for the single paragraph version, the command which saves the timestamp, formats and prints it is an order of magnitude slower than then the vpack. Therefore this constant dominates your benchmark until you have quite a lot of paragraphs.